# Python Lambda - Basic Auth for API calls in Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, authentication, lambda

I am trying to make an api call to an outside system using AWS Lambda. This is to going to be used to gather information about files as they arrive in the S3 bucket.

I am receiving a 403 forbidden error when attempting to make the REST API call. I believe there is an issue with how I am formatting the username and passkey needed for authentication. Does this need to be done in a specific way for Python 3.6 Lambdas to connect?

```
import boto3
import requests

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
myurl = "https://my-url/"

# These will be stored in AWS KMS for production system
username = 'username'
passkey = 'passkey'

headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')


    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        file_name = obj.key.split('/', 2).pop()
        file_name_no_ext = file_name[:-5]


        if file_name != '':
            if file_name.endswith('.json'):
                Final_File_name = file_name_no_ext + '.mxf'
                url = myurl + 'mypath/'+ Final_File_name
                response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=(username, passkey))
```